# Visit multiple URL's in loop in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on integrating a third party SMS application. The requirement is to send SMS to ten mobile numbers on **single** click of button on a web page at my site.

We have been provided with a URL in which we have to add a phone number and message to be sent. The URL accepts only **ONE** phone number at a time.

I have a list of phone numbers to which I have to send the same message one by one .
On looping through the list , I add a phone number to url and do **`Response.Redirect(url)`** in each iteration.

But this only ends up sending SMS to the first phone number in list as first time **`Response.Redirect()`** occurs , it takes browser to external site specified by the given Url and rest of for loop is not executed i.e rest of phone numbers are not embedded in url.

```
string[] phNos = { "91999999998", "91999999996" ,"91999999995"}; // Sample Mobile nos.

for(int i=0;i<phNos.Length;i++)
{

url = "baseurl/PushURL.fcgi?0&mobileno=" + phNos[i] + "&message="+ masg;

Response.Redirect(url);

}
```

I read about **`Server.Transfer()`** but this is can't be used for sending to external site.
Is my requirement feasible ? Please help how can I implement it .

Comment: See HttpWebRequest or WebClient

Comment: Try using `System.Net.WebClient` and that you download the sites instead that the user visits them

Comment: @L.B..ok. Going Thanks for responding...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Response.Redirect redirects the *users* browser to the given URL, as you found out.

What you want to do is to have your server access the URL(s) needed, using server-to-server communication. You can use WebClient to easily do this.

```
var cli = new System.Net.WebClient();
for(int i=0;i<phNos.Length;i++)
{
    url = "baseurl/PushURL.fcgi?0&mobileno=" + phNos[i] + "&message="+ masg;
    cli.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Note that this will retrieve the urls, effectively calling the API, *sequentially* and *synchronously*, which might not be what you want. If you want to do it in parallel, you can use `DownloadStringAsync` on WebClient, but you will need to code a mechanism that lets you wait until all the requests finished. This depends on what you want, how many numbers there might be, and your performance constraints.

Comment: Depending on how long each call takes (and especially if there are even more receivers), you might want to look into threading. Example witj ThreadPool:

`// Inside loop:
ThreadPool. QueueUserWorkItem(() =>
{
    // Connect to SMS-service here
});`

Comment: @PatrikW, I address exactly that in the last paragraph, just suggesting using the async API instead. Simpler, IMO, and not wasting a thread pool thread.

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry. I'd say using ThreadPool is mighty simple though. It's one method call with one parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using HttpWebRequest or WebClient

for instance

```
for(int i=0;i<phNos.Length;i++)
{
  try
  {
    url = "baseurl/PushURL.fcgi?0&mobileno=" + phNos[i] + "&message="+ masg;

    Uri targetUri = new Uri(url);
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest hwb;
    hwb = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
    hwb.GetResponse();
  }
  catch (...)
  { // error handling
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for helping me out...Tried your solution..But SMS is being sent only to first mobile no in array .  I am studying HttpWebRequest as suggested by all

Answer (score 1):

This kind of process should be performed by a webservice / WCF (on an application server), so using the webclient as above however the asp.net page should call a WCF service to perform the actions you need.

Web pages are not really for this kind of thing even though it is possible.

Comment: Yes you are right..web services are the way to do background work..will study them..thanx for responding.